react.js - Proxy Setup Not Working With Vite
I'm new to React.js and have been learning from various tutorials. I was trying to setup a proxy for a local-server based API call however I get this error after running the 'npm run dev' command.
Cannot create property 'prependPath' on boolean 'true'

I'm using Vite and have my proxy settings/code as
proxy: {
  '/api': 'http://localhost:8000',
  changeOrigin: true,
  rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
}

I'm not sure what the error means or how to fix it seeing that I'm still learning, can anyone help me with this?

According to the doc, changeOrigin and rewrite should be keys under the value of '/api':
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:8000',
    changeOrigin: true,
    rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
  }
}


Ahhh ofcourse!! Thank you!
